# How busy is python during a do-nothing loop?

Tags: python, loops, raspberry-pi

The context is raspberry pi, and the case in which you perform an action on one thing (e.g. sending a signal) and wait for something to happen (e.g. receive a response on another "channel", in the widest meaning of the world), i.e. something that might "look like" a call but in fact it is not.

For example think about a reaction game, in which the payer has to press a button rapidly after a led is lit.

- A led is lit
- The system waits until the button is pressed
- When the button is pressed, the wait ends and something happens (e.g. delta time is calculated)

My first (and working) attempt and the examples I find around work the following way:

```
def button_not_still_pressed():
    return True if "Button has not been still pressed", e.g. voltage is low
    # this function does the check (e.g. reads a pin or performs any other test
    # depending on the application

while button_not_still_pressed():
    pass # Please note: non tome.sleep() here

do_whatever_when_button_is_pressed()
```

In practice, it seems to work.

My concerns are:

- Can an indefinite/long loop cause the system hang?
- What does python do, in general, in a while loop like the one above?
- In particular, regarding devices like those, which is the best way to perform such a task of sending a signal and wait?

Comment: Its common for APIs to have a wait or notification mechanism. In that case, python transitions to the underlying C library that does a thread level suspend until the action or a timeout takes place. During that time the CPU is free to take on other threads. In your case when polling, python tries to consume the entire CPU. It may be switched out for other tasks by the operating system anyway, but you'd expect a tight loop like this to impact system performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can an indefinite/long loop cause the system hang?

In a more embedded system, yes. In Linux, probably not, since it's not doing anything of consequence.

> What does python do, in general, in a while loop like the one above?

Runs its interpreter in a tight loop that consumes CPU.

> In particular, regarding devices like those, which is the best way to perform such a task of sending a signal and wait?

If you're using Raspberry Pi's GPIO for your button, [use an interrupt](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/#interrupts-and-edge-detection) to avoid a tight loop:

```
GPIO.wait_for_edge(channel, GPIO.RISING)
```